# In Tensorflow how to deal with Input and Out_backprop must have the same batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to repeat an experiment involved in the paper called Composite Functional Gradient Learning of Generative Adversarial Models. In this process, I have met an error that I have never seen before. I do not know what causes this problem. I hope someone who can help me. Thank you so much!

The following is my coding. I think the problem is at 'self.generator(index, reuse=True)'.

The self.zs is defined as follow.

```
self.sz = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(self.sz_num, self.z_dim)).astype(np.float32)
```

I just want to sample 64 pieces of data from self.sz as the input for my generator.

```
 # Update the G network
            if self.iteration == 1:
                for i in range(0, 10):
                    index_g = self.sz[i:(i+1)*self.batch_size]
                    temp = self.generator(index_g, reuse=True)
                    self.prev_G_tf.append(temp)
                    temp = temp.eval(session=self.sess)
                    self.prev_G.extend(temp)
```

Every time, I run this code, I get the error as the following.

```
Caused by op 'generator_2/g_h1_deconv/conv2d_transpose', defined at:
File "G:/deep_learning/XICFG/main.py", line 107, in <module>tf.app.run()
File "C:\Users\XJTU-GY\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "G:/deep_learning/XICFG/main.py", line 90, in main
dcgan.train(FLAGS)
  File "G:\deep_learning\XICFG\model.py", line 239, in train
temp = self.generator(index_g, reuse=True)
  File "G:\deep_learning\XICFG\model.py", line 336, in generator
self.h1 = deconv2d(self.h0, [self.batch_size, 7, 7, self.gf_dim * 2], name='g_h1_deconv', with_w=False)
   File "G:\deep_learning\XICFG\ops.py", line 75, in deconv2d
strides=[1, d_h, d_w, 1])
  File "C:\Users\XJTU-    GY\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 1258, in conv2d_transpose
name=name)
  File "C:\Users\XJTU-GY\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 1336, in conv2d_backprop_input
dilations=dilations, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\XJTU-GY\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\XJTU-GY\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3290, in create_op
op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\XJTU-GY\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1654, in __init__
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Conv2DSlowBackpropInput: input and out_backprop must have the same batch sizeinput batch: 64outbackprop batch: 127 batch_dim: 0
     [[Node: generator_2/g_h1_deconv/conv2d_transpose = Conv2DBackpropInput[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 2, 2], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](generator_2/g_h1_deconv/conv2d_transpose-0-LayoutOptimizer, generator/g_h1_deconv/w/read, generator_2/g_h1_deconv/conv2d_transpose-2-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer)]]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The details about my generator are as the following.

```
    def generator(self, z, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("generator") as scope:
        if reuse:
            scope.reuse_variables()

        if self.dataset_name == 'mnist':

            self.z_, self.h0_w, self.h0_b = linear(z, self.gf_dim * 4 * 4 * 4, 'g_h0_lin', with_w=True)

            self.h0 = tf.nn.relu(tf.reshape(self.z_, [-1, 4, 4, self.gf_dim * 4]))
            self.h1 = deconv2d(self.h0, [self.batch_size, 7, 7, self.gf_dim * 2], name='g_h1_deconv', with_w=False)
            self.h1 = tf.nn.relu(self.g_bn1(self.h1))
            self.h2 = tf.nn.relu(self.g_bn2(conv2d_1(self.h1, self.gf_dim * 2, name='g_h2_conv')))
            self.h3 = tf.nn.relu(self.g_bn3(deconv2d(self.h2, [self.batch_size, 14, 14, self.gf_dim * 1],
                                                     name='g_h3_deconv', with_w=False)))
            self.h4 = tf.nn.relu(self.g_bn4(conv2d_1(self.h3, self.gf_dim * 1, name='g_h4_conv')))
            h5 = tf.nn.tanh(deconv2d(self.h4, [self.batch_size, 28, 28, self.c_dim]))
            return h5
```

Comment: Good work, this is a lot better.

Comment: Have you seen that error before? I do not know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I know what is wrong with my code. Due to my careless, I should write this line as follow.

```
index_g = self.sz[i*self.batch_size:(i+1)*self.batch_size]
```

In such case, I do not get an error any more.